# To free the pallets from a wait block with a dynamic event

Tags: anylogic

I would like to free the different amount of pallets sitting in my wait block to the certain time. I don't know how to use the free function in my dynamic event. The database is called lkw76 and my different pallet amounts called amount in my database which are released to the certain date. So I have the wait block where the pallets sit in before they will be released to the time of my database. So I need the function for my dynamic event which release the amount of pallets in my wait block. In main on startup I have following function to connect the dynamic event with my database. In general I don't have java knowledge so I am currently in the process to learn it. Thank you for helping.

```
List< Tuple > amounts =selectFrom( lkw76 ).list();
for( Tuple tup : amounts ) {
    Date today=date();
    Date future=tup.get(lkw76.dates);
    long diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    int amount=tup.get(lkw76.amount);
    create_MyDynamicEvent(diff,MILLISECOND,amount);
}
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MULRs.png)

[dynamic_event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JefwR.png)

[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4vXD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this in the dynamic event:

```
for(int i=min(amount,wait.size());i>0;i--){
   wait.free(wait.get(i-1));
}
```

This implies FIFO and will free the first amount agents that entered the wait block, unless there are less agents in the wait block, in which case it will free all of them

Comment: Do you know why it only releases half of the amount I would like to release/ half of the amount I inject in source? When I inject 30 at 6 am it releases 15 pallets at the time of the dbase. Next time it releases also the half of my required amount

Comment: When the amount is double of the pallets I inject it also only releases half of the inject pallets. So I inject 50 pallets and the amount in my dbase is 100 it also only releases 25 from the wait block

Comment: i don't know... seems weird

Comment: When I change source from arrival table in database to another arrival method it doesn't free something anymore. strange

Comment: Don't know why it doesnt't take the amount of my column amount when it comes to the wait block to free the pallets

Comment: upload your model somewhere, otherwise it will take ages to help you out...

Comment: I asked the sof community once again, maybe someone can help me. If not I will consider other things.. nevertheless thank you for your help the last days!